# Get childview of adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I have an adapter with 2 layout the fisrt one is the song item with the details and the second layout is the song item with the details and a seekbar for the playback position of current song selected layout. My adapter is here :

```
package org.mrhands.player.adapter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.mrhands.player.DataHelper;
import org.mrhands.player.R;
import org.mrhands.player.model.AudioFile;
import org.mrhands.player.service.MusicService;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AlphabetIndexer;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class LaguListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
AlphabetIndexer indexer;
List<AudioFile> listAudioFile;
Context context;
final int LIST_LAGU = 0;
final int LIST_LAGU_WITH_SEEKBAR = 1;
int currentlyPlay = -1;
OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener;
HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;

/**
 * parameter ini digunakan untuk mendapatkan seekbar dari view yang terpilih
 * dari adapter
 * 
 * @param currentlyPlay
 */
public void setCurrentlyPlay(int currentlyPlay) {
    this.currentlyPlay = currentlyPlay;
}
public AudioFile getCurrentPlay(){
    return listAudioFile.get(currentlyPlay);
}

String[] sections;
String sortedColumn = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
MusicService service;
public LaguListAdapter(Context context, List<AudioFile> listAudioFile,OnSeekBarChangeListener listener,MusicService service) {
    this.context = context;
    this.onSeekBarChangeListener=listener;
    this.service=service;
    this.listAudioFile = listAudioFile;
    alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // in this hashmap we will store here the positions for
    // the sections

    int size = listAudioFile.size();
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        AudioFile element = listAudioFile.get(i);
        alphaIndexer.put(element.getTitle().substring(0, 1), i);
        // We store the first letter of the word, and its index.
        // The Hashmap will replace the value for identical keys are putted
        // in
    }

    // now we have an hashmap containing for each first-letter
    // sections(key), the index(value) in where this sections begins

    // we have now to build the sections(letters to be displayed)
    // array .it must contains the keys, and must (I do so...) be
    // ordered alphabetically

    Set<String> keys = alphaIndexer.keySet(); // set of letters ...sets
    // cannot be sorted...

    Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
    ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list can be
    // sorted

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        keyList.add(key);
    }

    Collections.sort(keyList);

    sections = new String[keyList.size()]; // simple conversion to an
    // array of object
    keyList.toArray(sections);

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView textJudulLagu;
    TextView textPenyanyi;
    ImageView imageLagu;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    int ref;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);//ambil tipe dari layout adapter
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (viewType == LIST_LAGU) {//cek jika layout yang terpilih adalah list lagu maka gunakan layout list lagu
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_lagu, null);
        } else if (viewType == LIST_LAGU_WITH_SEEKBAR) {//yang ini menggunakan layout seekbar
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_lagu_with_seekbar, null);
            holder.seekbar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek_lagu);
            holder.seekbar.setMax((int) service.getCurrentPlay().getDuration());
            holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);

        }
        holder.imageLagu = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_lagu_gambar);
        holder.textPenyanyi = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_lagu_penyanyi);
        holder.textJudulLagu = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_lagu_judul);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.ref = position;
    AudioFile file = listAudioFile.get(position);
    holder.textPenyanyi.setText(file.getArtist());
    holder.textJudulLagu.setText(file.getTitle());
    Bitmap b;
    try {
        b = DataHelper.getAlbumArtBitmap(context, file);
        holder.imageLagu.setImageBitmap(b);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        holder.imageLagu.setImageDrawable(context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.albumart));
    }
    return view;
}

public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    String letter = sections[section];
    return alphaIndexer.get(letter);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == currentlyPlay ? LIST_LAGU_WITH_SEEKBAR : LIST_LAGU;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    // you will notice it will be never called (right?)
    Log.v("getSectionForPosition", "called");
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    return sections;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listAudioFile.size();
}

}
```

In this adapter I only set the seekbar to be shown when the user click the adapter using onItemClickListener and then I want to get the Seekbar on the selected adapter. How can I do it? I have made a method like this.. but not work.

```
public Seekbar getSeekbar(){
  ViewHolder view=(ViewHolder)getView(currentlyPlay,null,null);
  return view.seekBar;
}
```

I set the currentlyPlay view on my onItemClick so I can get the current Position the selected view..  But that is not work for me.. can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the view of specific position by

```
View clickedView = yourAdapter.getView(position, null, null);
```

Comment: can I use clickedView.findViewById(R.id.seek_lagu)?. I have been try it, but no components updated. Am I have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I have try it like this.. LaguListAdapter.ViewHolder holder=     (ViewHolder) adapter.getView(arg2, null, null).getTag();
   holder.seekbar.setProgress(50);
   holder.seekbar.setMax(100); but when I called notifyDataSetChanged there's no effect.. I guess it called the default getView that return the origin getView of adapter.. any other solution?